# Two Lists of strings: remove strings from list A that contain any string from list B?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of strings.

```
filters = ['foo', 'bar']

wordlist = ['hey', 'badge', 'foot', 'bar', 'cone']
```

I want to remove every word in the wordlist that contains a filter.

```
def filter_wordlist(filters, wordlist):

    for word in wordlist:
        if word contains any string from filters, remove it from the wordlist

    return wordlist
```

So this filter function would return `['hey', 'badge', 'cone']`. It removed `bar` because `bar` is in `filters`. It removed `foot` because it contains the string `foo`.

I tried this:

```
for word in wordlist:
    for f in filters:
        if f in word:
            wordlist.remove(word)
```

But it consistently returns `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`. So I tried wrapping it in a series of increasingly frustrating try/except blocks, but nothing down that gopher hole worked. I added a `break` statement below the remove command, but that was ... spotty. It seems like the items towards the end of the `wordlist` aren't getting filtered properly.

So I changed tactics to this:

```
for f in filters:
    for word in wordlist:
        if f in word:
            wordlist.remove(word)
```

This is spotty just like before.

So I tried this:

```
for word in wordlist:
    if any(f in word for f in filters):
        wordlist.remove(word)
```

And now it's definitely irritating me. Spotty. And by now, I've realized what's happening - using `remove()` is changing the list as I'm iterating over it, and that's screwing up the iteration.

This seems like it should be really simple. I have two lists of strings. Take all of the items in List A. If any of those items contain any item from List B, remove the item from List A.

This is the working solution I finally got:

```
keepitup = True

while keepitup:
    start_length = len(wordlist)
    for word in wordlist:
        if any(f in word for f in filters):
            wordlist.remove(link)
    end_length = len(wordlist)
    if start_length != end_length:
        keepitup = True
    else:
        keepitup = False
```

This seems ridiculous. Surely there's a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
wordlist = [word for word in wordlist if all(f not in word for f in filters)]
```

Or the filter function:

```
filter(lambda word: all(f not in word for f in filters), wordlist)
```

Or you could iterate over a copy of wordlist:

```
for word in wordlist[:]:
    if any(f in word for f in filters):
        wordlist.remove(word)
```

Comment: Elegant, simple, and explicit. I am starting to understand why people make such a big deal out of Python's list comprehension powers. This is awesome.

Comment: @souldeux Notice how grc's last example, which uses `remove()`, is working on a **copy** of `wordlist`, by using `[:]`. Attempting to use `remove()` on a list you're iterating over causes Bad Things™. I guess I should also mention that his list comprehension example is creating a totally new list and doesn't actually bind it to `wordlist` until the list is completely built. IOW, the `wordlist` on the left side of the `=` is a new, different object to the one on the right.

Comment: @PM2Ring very interesting! Thank you for expanding on this, sincerely.